# Improving testing.Benchmark for Go?

Tags: testing, go, benchmarking

In learning about Go, I see that you can benchmark a function using [`fmt.Println(testing.Benchmark(BenchmarkFunction))`](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark), having set up the following:

```
func BenchmarkFunction(b *testing.B) {
    n := 42
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = Function(n)
    }
}
```

However, as the `BenchmarkFunction` code would be repeated for every benchmark of every method you would do this for (hence a code smell, in terms of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), is there a way that this could be rewritten using closures (or in some other manner) such that a benchmark of a function could be rewritten something like:

```
fmt.println(test.BenchmarkMyFunction(MyFunction(parameters...)))
```

and added either into my code or the `testing` library?

Comment: Have a look at some of the test files for the standard library. http://golang.org/src/pkg/fmt/fmt_test.go seems to approach what you're after using structs, one of which, `val`, is an empty insterface (see line 115)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this is not the right way to do benchmarks in Go.

The actual standard is to put your benchmarking code into functions that have names `BenchmarkXXX` where XXX is whatever you like. Then you run `go test -bench=.` on the package that defines these files. `go test` is running all the benchmarks for you.

If you have similar benchmarks with slightly different parameters, you can write a generic benchmarking function that is just called by all the other benchmarks:

```
func genericBenchmarkFoo(b *testing.B, param int) { ... }
```

And then you write a boilerplate function for each specific benchmark:

```
func BenchmarkFoo1(b *testing.B) { genericBenchmarkFoo(b, 1) }
func BenchmarkFoo2(b *testing.B) { genericBenchmarkFoo(b, 2) }
func BenchmarkFoo3(b *testing.B) { genericBenchmarkFoo(b, 3) }
func BenchmarkFoo4(b *testing.B) { genericBenchmarkFoo(b, 4) }
```

You can find an example of this pattern in this [package](https://github.com/fuzxxl/qtv/tree/master/bitcomposer) I wrote.

Of course this is not exactly beautiful but I am afraid there is not an easier solution. It's clean coding however to find a small set of benchmarks that represent what you want to do.

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with people who downvote me. It is just difficult to do anything about it when people do not leave any sort of explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a real, simple, and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) Go benchmark, which uses closures. I wanted to know how the performance of a various `Substr` functions varied with the size (`hi` - `lo`) of the substring.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func Substr1(str string, lo, hi int) string {
    return string([]byte(str[lo:hi]))
}

func Substr2(str string, lo, hi int) string {
    sub := str[lo:hi]
    return (sub + " ")[:len(sub)]
}

func Substr3(str string, lo, hi int) string {
    sub := str[lo:hi]
    if len(sub) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    return sub[0:1] + sub[1:]
}

var substrFunctions = []struct {
    name     string
    function func(str string, lo, hi int) string
}{
    {"Substr1", Substr1},
    {"Substr2", Substr2},
    {"Substr3", Substr3},
}

var substrBenchmarks = []struct {
    name                 string
    strLen, subLo, subHi int
}{
    {"Zero  ", 1, 1, 1},
    {"Small ", 4, 1, 4},
    {"Medium", 256, 1, 256},
    {"Large ", 4096, 1, 4096},
}

func BenchmarkSubstrSize() {
    fmt.Println("BenchmarkSubstrSize:")
    for _, benchmark := range substrBenchmarks {
        str := strings.Repeat("abc", benchmark.strLen)
        for _, function := range substrFunctions {
            benchmarkFunc := func(b *testing.B) {
                b.ResetTimer()
                for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                    function.function(str, benchmark.subLo, benchmark.subHi)
                }
                b.StopTimer()
            }
            results := testing.Benchmark(benchmarkFunc)
            fmt.Println(benchmark.name, function.name, results)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    BenchmarkSubstrSize()
}
```

Output:

```
BenchmarkSubstrSize:
Zero    Substr1   50000000    54.8 ns/op
Zero    Substr2  100000000    19.6 ns/op
Zero    Substr3  500000000     6.66 ns/op
Small   Substr1   20000000    95.7 ns/op
Small   Substr2   50000000    70.4 ns/op
Small   Substr3   50000000    70.1 ns/op
Medium  Substr1    5000000   380 ns/op
Medium  Substr2   10000000   229 ns/op
Medium  Substr3   10000000   213 ns/op
Large   Substr1     500000  4290 ns/op
Large   Substr2    1000000  2007 ns/op
Large   Substr3    1000000  2275 ns/op
```

Comment: How would one adapt this to be used in a *_test.go file? I removed   `package main` and `func main()` and added `b *Testing.B` to `BenchmarkSubstrSize()` but I'm getting `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this can be considered a gain:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "testing"
)

func f1(n int) (s int) {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                s += i
        }
        return
}

func f2(n int) (s int) {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                s += 2 * i
        }
        return
}

func bench(f func()) func(b *testing.B) {
        return func(b *testing.B) {
                for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                        f()
                }
        }
}

func main() {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", testing.Benchmark(bench(func() { f1(42) })))
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", testing.Benchmark(bench(func() { f2(24) })))
}
```

---

Output:

```
(16:55) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/16920669$ go run main.go 
50000000            68.4 ns/op
50000000            35.8 ns/op
(16:55) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/16920669$
```